# How to do a bulk delete under condition in Django

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django, django-orm

There are several questions similar to mine but none are satisfactory. Some questions deal with the management of duplicates under conditions, others in the context of a database having a large number of lines but none which provide an efficient algorithm that take into account a condition.

I would like to be able to remove duplicates from a DB having more than 26 million lines, therefore in the most efficient way with the condition that I want to keep the row which has the most recent update date (updated is a field).

Is it possible to use the Django ORM or do we have to use SQL in that case?

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models. Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    soft_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    share_class__id = models. BigIntegerField()
    class_ccy = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tna_fund = models.FloatField(null=True)
    tna_class = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

For instance, let's say for each share_class_id, I have multiple rows with the same date. I want to keep the row which has the latest updated record.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please write a [mcve]. How do you define duplicate (date field is not duplicated) ? Be precise on what you expect as a result. Why other solution you have found are no fit for your use case ? What makes your problem different or not suitable for those solution ?

Comment: Are you able to select the duplicate as you wish using a distinct clause for instance ? If yes, why don't you bulk delete them ?

Comment: It would probably help if you could provide the model with the fields that you consider a duplicate.

Comment: @jlandercy: I think the question is how to delete these in bulk. But it would help if the OP just provided a (sample) model with the intended result.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a generic way to do this is:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

MyModel.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        MyMode.objects.filter(
            field1=OuterRef('field1'),
            field2=OuterRef('field2'),
            # …
            fieldn=OuterRef('fieldn'),
            time_field__gt=OuterRef('time_field'),
        )
    )
).delete()
```

it thus checks if there is a `MyModel` with the same values for a set of fields where you consider two items the same, which is more recent (`timefield__gt=OuterRef('time_field')`), and if that is the case, removes these items.

We can easily wrap this in a helper function:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


def get_deprecated(model, *fields, time_field='update_date'):
    return model._base_manager.filter(
        Exists(
            MyMode.objects.filter(
                **{
                    **{field: OuterRef(field) for field in fields},
                    f'{time_field}__gt': OuterRef(time_field),
                }
            )
        )
    )


def delete_deprecated(*args, **kwargs):
    return get_deprecated(*args, **kwargs).delete()
```

and then you thus can use this as:

```
delete_deprecated(MyModel, 'share_class_id', time_field='updated')
delete_deprecated(Price, 'product', 'color', 'size', time_field='update_date')
```

this will then remove `Price`s if for the same product, color and size, there is a more recent price. Beware that the time_field should *not* be NULLable, if there are NULLs, the behiavior is database specific and might result in problems.